# URL routing not working when user clicks a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to modify a web application we have and I'm not sure if I can do what is being requested. My boss wants to be able to click a link from an email and have our internal company web application go straight to a page identified at the end of a provided URL.

If I click on the link below the first time, it goes to the index page of our web application. If I leave the web application open and click on the link again, it goes to the correct page identified at the end of the URL.

```
http://mycompanyweb.com/handbook/mycompanyprocess/#/rt/softwate/9.13_UpdateSDP
```

I've tried adding an init(), thinking that is where the application goes first in the lifecycle and I only see this part of the URL at that point (http://mycompanyweb.com/handbook/mycompanyprocess/). This leads me to believe that the browser is stripping everything off after the # when it first opens. Is that correct? Is there something I can do to get our web application to go directly to the document the first time a user clicks on the link, without the web application open?

```
http://mycompanyweb.com/handbook/mycompanyprocess/ - Base URL

#/rt    - Used by our javascript engine to determine which path to take 
(dev or production).

/software/9.13_UpdateSDP    - Logical path to a web page named 6.034_UpdateSDP.htm
```

Our engine that determines where to route based on the URL. I assume that the second time a link is clicked that it goes to the correct page is because the engine has been loaded (provided the browser is left open when clicked a second time).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// Define the routes.
Path.map("#/:program").to(function () {
    var program = this.params['program'];

    if (program == "search") {
        $("#mainContent").load("search.html");
    }
    else {
        $("#mainContent").load("views/onepageprocess.html");
    }

    $("#subheader").html("");

    $("#headerLevelTwoBreadcrumbLink").html("");
}).enter(setPageActions);

Path.map("#/:program/:swimlane").to(function () {
    localStorage.removeItem("SearchString");

    var swimlane = this.params['swimlane'];

    var view = "views/" + swimlane + ".html";

    $("#mainContent").load(view);

}).enter(setPageActions);

// Sends all links to the level three view and updates the breadcrumb.
Path.map("#/:program/:swimlane/:page").to(function () {
    var page = this.params['page'];

var url = "views/levelthree/" + page.replace("", "") + ".htm";

var levelThreeTitle = "";

    $.get(url)
    .done(function () {
        // Nothing here at this time...
    }).fail(function () {
        url = "views/levelthree/badurlpage.htm";

        levelThreeTitle = "Page Unavailable";
    }).always(function (data) {
        $("#subheader").html("");

        level_three_breadcrumb = "views/breadcrumbs/breadcrumb_link.html";

        $("#headerLevelTwoBreadcrumbLink").load(level_three_breadcrumb);

        $("#headerLevelThreeBreadcrumb").html("");

        $('#headerLevelThreeBreadcrumb').append('<img src="images/Chevron.gif" />');

        if (data.status != "404") {
            $("#headerLevelThreeBreadcrumb").append(retrieveStorageItem("LevelThreeSubheader"));
        }

        $("#mainContent").load(url);
    });

}).enter(setPageActions);

// Set a "root route". User will be automatically re-directed here.  The definition
// below tells PathJS to load this route automatically if one isn't provided.
Path.root("#/rt");

// Start the path.js listener.
Path.listen();
});
```

Is there something I can do to get our web application to go directly to the document the first time a user clicks on the link, without the web application open?

Comment: the Browser will not strip anything from the URL. must have something todo with your application

Comment: Sooo, how can I find out where?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone runs into something like this, I found out that my company's servers were stripping anything after the # in the URL at authentication. I will be modifying my app to not use hash tags in the URL to fix it.